# SwiftUI Delete a View drag and drop in specific area

Tags: swift, swiftui, view, drag-and-drop, contextmenu

I'm trying to add a contextMenu to this view, but as it is draggable I think when it is dragged out of its frame when the contextMenu is displayed can't show the image into the view... I can see 2 possible solutions but I can't do it fine...
1- that the image is center into the frame when you call to the contextMenu...

2- drag and drop to an specific area to delete it...

Any Idea? could you help me? :)

Here the code...

```
 import SwiftUI

struct PiercingView: View {
    var piercing: Piercing
    @State private var position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    @ObservedObject var piercings: PiercingModel = .init()
    @State private var frame: CGFloat = 100

    @State private var magnify: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var lastMagnify: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var angle: Angle = .degrees(.zero)
    @State private var lastAngle: Angle = .degrees(.zero)
   
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            Image(piercing.image)
                .resizable()
                
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .position(position)
                
                .gesture(
                    DragGesture()
                        .onChanged { value in
                            position = value.location
                        }
                )
                .scaleEffect(self.magnify)
                .rotationEffect(self.angle)
                .gesture(RotationGesture()
                    .onChanged { angle in
                        self.angle = angle + self.lastAngle
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        self.lastAngle = self.angle
                    }
                )
                .simultaneousGesture(MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged { v in
                        let delta = v / self.lastMagnify
                        self.lastMagnify = v
                        self.magnify *= delta
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        self.lastMagnify = 1
                    }
                )
                .contextMenu(menuItems: {
                    Button(role: .destructive) {
                        piercings.deletePiercing(piercing: piercing)
                    }
                label: {
                    HStack {
                        Text("Delete")
                        Image(systemName: "trash")
                    }
                }
                })
              
        }.frame(width: frame, height: frame)
          
    }
}
```

[image: Here when I call contextMenu in the View]

[image: This is the other possible solution]

Thanks!